# Tableau context parameter

Tags: tableau-api

I have 3 dimensions in the following hierarchy:

```
BigC
  L  SmallC
        L  Brand
```

(Having 200 combinations)

I am also creating a calculation using a parameter and multiple case statements.

For eg: `CASE WHEN parameter=Brand1 THEN Brand1_field - Impact% END`

Now I want my parameter to have only the relevant brand values populated for Big C and Small C rather than all the values. Is it possible?

If this is not possible then can I create a calculated field with a column selection?

Comment: So I'm going to assume BigC and SmallC are the company names that live under the fields "Company" and "SmallCompany".

So are you asking for something like:
when Company = BigC and SmallCompany = SmallC give me back all the brands that sit under these companies?

Comment: Yes exactly, The Big Category and Small Categories are a hierarchy which has multiple brands under them. What I intend to do is filter only the relevant brands for myself when the Big C and Small C filters are selected.

PS-Brand is a parameter not a field

Comment: I'm not sure what your parameter is trying to achieve? Could you explain what your trying to do with it? You can pull parameters into calculated fields as part of the logic if that helps you?

If we leave the param out to get the brands living under BigC and SmallC should be reactively easy.

`IF [Company] = 'BigC' and [SmallCompany] = 'SmallC' THEN [Brand] ELSE 'Not Brand' END`

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your question properly, I was able to achieve this using Context filter and Filter by Relevant Values.

Drop both Big Company and Small Company dimensions into Filter Card.

Apply Context Filter for Big Company and "Use only relevant values" for Small Company filter.

So as when you select values for Big Company only the related values of small company will be displayed and so the brands.

Find the workbook here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/txam3wfhz8qirqg/StackOverflowSolution.twbx?dl=0